# Python pdb in terminal not showing recent commands

Tags: python, terminal, pdb

I'm not sure whether this is actually a PDB issue or a terminal issue, but when I press the up arrow (to look for recently used commands), the output shows `(Pdb) ^[[A`. If I am using a very basic hello world type of python program, I don't have this problem. I'm getting it while working with a complicated Google app engine application, if that helps at all.

Is there any workaround or way to avoid this?

Comment: Are you debugging both programs with the same terminal session, on the same server? It looks like your key settings are messed up.

Comment: just app engine in one terminal (it runs continuously)... the server is my local machine, and there's a ton of stuff running so i'm not sure how to answer that

Answer (score 0):

You can not use pdb with app engine, the way you use it with django or anything. You have to copy the line and then paste it. It will not work if you use arrow keys.

Read https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/02/28/debugging-app-engine-application-with-python-pdb-debugger/

I hope this helps you, as I've never used it, in a way explained in above link.